# jQuery click not appending values appropriately to textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to append a word in the word bank `wordBank_Headings` to the textbox `#textBox`.

My jQuery is working because I've tested the click function with other elements, such as `$("#textBox").click(function (event) {`, then `log("testing : " + $(this).attr('word'));` outputs "testing : undefined".

When a user clicks on a word, it will be sent to the textbox:

[image]

I checked HTML in Chrome. I see the words are being wrapped appropriately in the `spans`.

[image]

I'm not sure why clicking on the words won't work though.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //initially append words to word bank   
    $.getJSON("php/Quests.php", { "_questNum" : questNum},
        function(wordsArray) {
            $.each(wordsArray, function(key, value) {   
                $(".wordBank_Words").append("<span class='bankword' word='" + key + "' ><b>" + key + "</b>: " + value + "</span><br/>");
            }
        );
    });

    /*If user clicks word in word bank, word is added to text box*/
    $(".bankword").click(function (event) {
        log("testing : " + $(this).attr('word'));
        $('#textBox').val($('#textBox').val() + " " + $(this).attr('word'));        
        //hide word from word bank
        $(this).hide();
    });


    /*If User removes word from text box, add it back to word bank*/
    $('#textBox').on('change', function(){
        var words = $(this).val().split(' ');
        $('.bankword').each(function(){
           if( words.indexOf( $(this).attr('word') ) !== -1 ){
               $(this).hide();
           }
           else {
               $(this).show();
           }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't create your own attributes for elements. Use `data-XXX` for application data.

Comment: @Barmar can you please explain what you mean? Why not?

Comment: Because they might some day conflict with standard attributes. `data-XXX` are explicitly reserved for applications and will never conflict.

Comment: @Barmar So I tried doing `$(".wordBank_Words").append("<span class='bankword' data-display-word='" + key +....` But this still doesn't append.

Comment: I never said this would fix your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: I agree with Barmar, you could also use the jQuery data function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you create a span element after document is created. So, you should try `on` for your `click` event. you can try as below:

```
$(document).on('click',".bankword",function (event) {
   log("testing : " + $(this).attr('word'));
   $('#textBox').val($('#textBox').val() + " " + $(this).attr('word'));        
   //hide word from word bank
   $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You know what? Looks like You try to attach listeners to the spans before they're created. You just have to replace this line

```
$(".bankword").click(function (event) {
```

with this one

```
$(".wordBank_Words").on('click', ".bankword", function (event) {
```